# schedule - how many ticks ago?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Is there a way to have a reference to schedule and find out how many times it has already ticked by using the schedule object itself?

[self schedule:@selector(a:) interval:1.0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

increment a variable within your class to determine how many times it has "ticked".  The scheduler does not keep such information available, it does however pass the time since the last tick occurred.